# which join gives better performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, join

which is better performance between join after filtering or filtering after join?
example

```
...
INNER JOIN
  (select * from dbo.tblCMEvalEmail 
   where dbo.tblCMEvalEmail.EmailSentDate BETWEEN '2013-05-16 00:00:00'
                                              AND '2013-06-01 23:59:59')
     as TCMEvalEmail  ON dbo.tblTSAEmail.TSAEmail = TCMEvalEmail.EmailSenderEmail
INNER JOIN 
  (select * from dbo.tblCMEvalEmailInfo 
   where dbo.tblCMEvalEmailInfo.EmailCMFacingDate BETWEEN '2013-05-16 00:00:00'
                                                      AND '2013-06-01 23:59:59')
     as TEmailInfo ON TCMEvalEmail.EmailID = TEmailInfo.EmailID
```

or

```
INNER JOIN dbo.tblCMEvalEmail
   ON dbo.tblTSAEmail.TSAEmail = dbo.tblCMEvalEmail.EmailSenderEmail 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblCMEvalEmailInfo
   ON dbo.tblCMEvalEmail.EmailID = dbo.tblCMEvalEmailInfo.EmailID 
WHERE 
  dbo.tblCMEvalEmail.EmailSentDate BETWEEN '2013-05-16 00:00:00'
                                       AND '2013-06-01 23:59:59' 
  AND dbo.tblCMEvalEmailInfo.EmailCMFacingDate BETWEEN '2013-05-16 00:00:00'
                                                   AND '2013-06-01 23:59:59'
```

Comment: What does the execution plan say? What happened when you tried?

Comment: Why are you asking humans? Just measure it.

Comment: Profiler is your friend.

Comment: The accepted answer is incorrect. In your particular case, the query planner will rewrite the query in exactly the same way anyway, meaning it'll make no performance difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the scenario and the data you have. Rule of the thumb is get the minimal required data and filter it further. Depending on the data, sometimes JOIN followed by filer may be better but on a different dataset the vice-versa may be better. So you need to identify which one is helping you more by running both the queries and measuring the performance.